# Database Design in MySql for User's Stock Market Performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I am designing an app for the stock market, where users can track their performance, on a intra day, weekly, and monthly displays.

For the Database Design, should I create a new table for every new user, to track their portfolio?

Something like this for the table for User x:

Date -  date

Time -  time

Close -  decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should not create a table for each user.  You should have tables such as this:

- `Users` with one row per user.
- `Portfolios` with one row per portfolio (assuming there could be 0 or more portfolios per user).
- `Stocks` with one row per stock.
- `PortfolioStocks` with one row per portfolio and stock.

Of course, there are a bunch of other columns in the tables -- such as when a stock in a portfolio or the tax id number of the user.  And this is an illustration to show that you don't want a separate table for each user.  You want a fixed number of tables with the ability to add users and stocks and portfolios as desired.

Comment: Oh ok I see where you're going with this. So I will just have a large number of columns in Portfolio per User? Let's say if I'm storing minute data daily, which is around 450 columns?

Comment: @Chris . . . Sounds like those would be in separate rows in some sort of "stock price by minute" table.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry I'm new to database management and design. So I will have a seperate table, just for minute data of a User's portfolio performance?  Let's say for one day, there are 450 minute data ticks, which would result in 450 rows for that specific user? What if there are multiple users? All those users would store their minute data ticks in the same "stock price by minute" table?

Comment: @chris yes. At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial on relational databases (and specifically, normalisation) would be immensely useful. In general, if the insertion of ordinary new data requires structural change to the database , then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: +1. Thank you for your answer, @GordonLinoff. Could you clarify how would `Portfolios` and `StockPortfolios` would look like ? What would be some sample fields ?